# Updating rendered partial variable via ajax in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm rendering a partial that contains a collection_select that uses a variable as a collection object.

Is there any way to update this variable via ajax?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are rendering partial like this

```
<div id="some_id">
  <%= render partial: 'path_to_partial', locals: {variable: @variable} %>
</div>
```

When sends ajax call to a `controller` `action` create a `.js` page for that action.

```
 # action.js.erb
    $('#some_id').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "path_to_partial", locals: {variable: @variable_with_new_values}) %>');
```

This will update the partial with new values.